# How to change build target to lower versions?

Tags: android, build, target

How do I change the build target of my app from 4.3.1 to 4.0? When I tried to change it I receive lots of errors such as

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignStart' in package 'android'
>   Multiple markers at this line
>       - listView1 cannot be resolved or is 
>        not a field
>       - R cannot be resolved to a variable
>   The import com.vote.system.R cannot be resolved

EDIT: I Already solved the problem, I exported the R.java from my Android 4.3 in the project, then changed the build target, and imported the R.java again and it works fine

Comment: what IDE you using? In android studio you can right click on the project and select Open Module settings and do the appropriate settings

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, i've already tried changing the build target in the properties, but when I do that the project receives tons of errors, I think it's in the R.id part

Comment: what is the error you getting

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_marginStart' with value '?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart').

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignStart' in package 'android'

R cannot be resolved to a variable

The import com.vote.system.R cannot be resolved

Comment: try cleaning the project

Comment: Yes, after changing the build target to 4.0 or 4.0.3 I'll clean it, then after cleaning all the errors will show up (or when I try to export it without cleaning)

Comment: The attribute `android:layout_marginStart` was added in API 17, as the documentation says: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL. I'm afraid you are not able to use it when the targetSdkVersion has to be lower than 17...

Comment: Ahhh damn so that's why, what about the R.id part? did it vanished along with the 4.3 when it was replaced by 4.0?

Anyway what does the marginStart does? can I remove it safely or replace it with another code?

Answer (score 2):

For Eclipse:
1) Go to Manifest File
2) Change minSDK, targetSDK and compileSDK to your desired values.
3) Clean and Rebuild.

For Android Studio:
1)Right click your project (on the left hand side in the "Project Panel"
2) Open Module settings (2nd last option most probably)
3) Go to app
4) In properties tab, select compile SDK version.
5) In flavours tab, change target and min SDK
6) Clean and Rebuild Project.

In android studio u can also go to build.gradle and change min, target and compilse SDK values, but not prefereed if you are beginner.
Sometimes, android studio/eclipse needs to be restarted.